# How to get the date interval for each week in a given month?

Tags: php, date

Is there a way to get the date start/end for each week in PHP given a month?
So for example if i take this month(Nov 2011) i need to return

```
30 Oct ->  5 Nov
 6 Nov -> 12 Nov
13 Nov -> 19 Nov
20 Nov -> 26 Nov
27 Nov ->  3 Dec
```

LE:

Here's what i made in case some one else needs it. The code is not pretty but it works as i need it.

```
public function getMonthWeeks($month, $year)
{
    $month = intval($month);

    if ($month < 1) {
        $month = 1;
    }

    if ($month > 12) {
        $month = 12;
    }

    $tsfdOfMonth = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1, $year);
    $dayOfWeek   = idate('w', $tsfdOfMonth);

    $tIntervalStart = $tsfdOfMonth;
    $tNextMonth     = idate('m', strtotime("+1 month", $tsfdOfMonth));

    if ($dayOfWeek > 0) {
        $tStr = sprintf("-%d %s",
            $dayOfWeek,
            $dayOfWeek == 1 ? 'day' : 'days'
        );
        $tIntervalStart = strtotime($tStr, $tsfdOfMonth);
    }

    $resultDates = array();

    $tsStart = $tIntervalStart;
    $tsEnd   = strtotime('+6 days', $tsStart);

    while (true) {
        $rObj = new stdClass;
        $rObj->LinkStr = sprintf("%s %s - %s %s",
            date('M', $tsStart), date('d', $tsStart),
            date('M', $tsEnd),   date('d', $tsEnd)
        );
        $rObj->DateStart = date('Y-m-d', $tsStart);
        $rObj->DateEnd   = date('Y-m-d', $tsEnd);

        $resultDates[] = $rObj;

        if (idate('m', strtotime('+1 day',  $tsEnd)) == $tNextMonth) {
            break;
        }

        $tsStart = strtotime('+1 day',  $tsEnd);
        $tsEnd   = strtotime('+6 days', $tsStart);
    }

    return $resultDates;
}
```

Comment: There already is a number of questions asking how to [Get the first day of a week](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=first+day+of+week+php). Once you have that day, it is trivial to [add seven days](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=add+days+php). Please go through those questions and update your own question explaining what the difficulty is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to write a function:

Algorithm:

1. Get day of week of first of month.
2. Subtract necessary number of days to reach a Sunday--you now have date of the first "sunday" of the month (possibly last sunday of previous month).
3. Add six days to determine the Saturday of that week.
4. Add one day to determine the Sunday of the next week.
5. repeat 3 and 4 until we are no longer in the current month

Two features will be very helpful: `$saturdaytimestamp = strtotime("+6 days", $sundaytimestamp)` and `$dayofweek = idate('w', $timestamp);`

Answer (score 2):

You should use these functions - cal_days_in_month, strtotime, date

```
$aMonthWeeks = get_month_week_day_ranges(2011, 11);
print_r( $aMonthWeeks );

function get_month_week_day_ranges ( $year, $month ) {
    $last_month_day_num = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month, $year); 

    $first_month_day_timestamp = strtotime($year.'-'.$month.'-01');
    $last_month_daty_timestamp = strtotime($year.'-'.$month.'-'.$last_month_day_num );

    $first_month_week = date('W', $first_month_day_timestamp);
    $last_month_week = date('W', $last_month_daty_timestamp);

    $aMonthWeeks = array();
    for( $week = $first_month_week; $week <= $last_month_week; $week ++ ) {
        echo sprintf('%dW%02d-1', $year, $week ), "\n";
        array_push( $aMonthWeeks, array(  
            date("d:m:Y", strtotime( sprintf('%dW%02d-1', $year, $week ) ) ),
            date("d:m:Y", strtotime( sprintf('%dW%02d-7', $year, $week ) ) ),
        ) );
    }
    return $aMonthWeeks;
}
```

For my locale (the first day of week is **monday**) the result is

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 31:10:2011
            [1] => 06:11:2011
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 07:11:2011
            [1] => 13:11:2011
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 14:11:2011
            [1] => 20:11:2011
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 21:11:2011
            [1] => 27:11:2011
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 28:11:2011
            [1] => 04:12:2011
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know what the best way to do this is, but this could work: you ask PHP what day of week is the first day of the month like `date('w', mktime(0, 0, 0, (int)date('m'), 1, (int)date('Y'));` and then you can count down to the first day of the week, use the `checkdate()` function to determine the last day of the previous month, then build your array with a simple `while()` until you reach a week you ending but not starting in the next month.

Answer (score 0):

I just took the time to code this for you, and this will output what you want:

```
<?php

/* CONFIG */

$year = 2011;

$month = 11;

/* CODE */

$first_day = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1, $year);

$month_first_day = date('w', $first_day);

if($month_first_day != 1) {

    $offset = $month_first_day - 1;

    $previous_month = ($month == 1 ? mktime(0, 0, 0, 12, 1, ($year - 1)) : mktime(0, 0, 0, ($month - 1), 1, $year));

    $previous_month_days = date('t', $previous_month);

    $previous_month_saturday = $previous_month_days - $offset;

    $previous_month_stamp = ($month == 1 ? mktime(0, 0, 0, 12, $previous_month_saturday, ($year - 1)) : mktime(0, 0, 0, ($month - 1), $previous_month_saturday, $year));

    $first_saturday = $previous_month_stamp;

}else{

    $first_saturday = $first_day;

}

$loops = date('t', $first_day);

$loops = round($loops / 7);

for($loop = 1; $loop < ($loops + 2); $loop++) {

    echo date('j M', $first_saturday + ((7 * ($loop - 1)) * 24 * 60 * 60)) . ' -> ' . date('j M', $first_saturday + (((7 * $loop) - 1) * 24 * 60 * 60)) . '<br />';

}
```

This may not be the most effective way of achieving the goal. However, it gets what you've asked for done, and it gives you a general idea of how this could be accomplished.

Comment: I didn't. I up voted. I guess there are some people who don't like that you gave me the solution? And they would've preferred only giving me pointers so i can solve it myself. Which i did, i almost got my version running. Anyway thank you for taking time to answer my question.