# Create <select> in PHP with list of dates by week

Tags: php, date

I'll start with an example. How do I create a `<select>` field which contains a selection of dates arranged by week. The week being starting at Sunday ending on Saturday:

```
// Today is Feb 25
<select>
    <option value="2013-02-24" selected>Feb 24 - March 2</option>
    <option value="2013-02-17">Feb 17 - Feb 23</option>
    <option value="2013-02-10">Feb 10 - Feb 16</option>
    <option value="2013-02-03">Feb 3 - Feb 9</option>
</select>
```

As you can see in the example above, everything is arranged in groups of 7 (one week). I only placed the most recent 4 weeks which includes this week.

Comment: How about the answers here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8307805/how-to-get-the-date-interval-for-each-week-in-a-given-month

Comment: RTLM: http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php  http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<select>
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
    echo '<option value="' . date("Y-m-d", strtotime("this sunday - $i week")) . '">' . date("M j", strtotime("this sunday - $i week")) . " - " . date("M j", strtotime("this saturday - $i week")) .'</option>';
}
?>
</select>
```

Comment: +1 for `strtotime("this sunday")` and `strtotime("this saturday")`

Comment: Simply amazing use of `strtotime()`.

Comment: @enchance There is actually a better use of [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php). See updated answer.